# How to define SQL execution order for Update in Spring Data JPA OneToMany relation?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

Lets say I have my entities defined Like this -

```java
@Entity
class GrandParent {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "grandParent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList()<>;

    @Column
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
class Parent {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "grandparent_id", nullable = false)
    private GrandParent grandParent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList()<>;

    @Column
    private String name;

    ...

}
```

```java
@Entity
class Child {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    @Column
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

Now I want to update my child entity's name. So, I am doing the following -

```java
GrandParent grandParent = new GrandParent(); // Assume all values are present.
grandParent.getParents().forEach(parent -> {
    parent.setName("New Parent Name");
    parent.getChildren().forEach(child -> {
        child.setName("New Child Name");
    });
});

grandParentRepository.save(grandParent);
```

This works fine, and all the updates are persisted to the database as expected. I have the following questions now -

1. How does JPA decide which update query to execute first? Will the child table be updated first or the parent table?
2. Is it possible to customize the order in which these queries are executed? (I want the child tables to be updated first, and then only the parent tables to be updated due to data integrity constraints on the tables.)

Tried changing the order in which the code is executed, but it was of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your code is running in one transaction. In that case at the end of transaction Hibernate flushes the changes [in the specific order](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-order). All of the modified entities will be updated in the database in the same order as they were loaded into the transaction. In you case it's from parents to children. But for example, if you add `childRepository.findById(1)` in the beginning of you code - that child will be loaded before the parent and will be updated the first too.

To force Hibernate update children before the parents you can add `someRepository.flush();` after `child.setName()`.

If you want to check the order of operations - just turn on the [show-sql](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) property and look at the SQL statements in the log.